# WordPress: Get post ID in a php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I did some research over the web and I couldn’t find a way to get post / page id in a php file that serves as a dynamic stylesheet.

The current config of the file (style.php) looks like:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8' );
[...]
define('WP_EXTERNAL', true);
require_once( $base .'wp-load.php' );

global $post;
$meta_info = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_metakey', true );
?>
h1.tut {
  background-color: <?php echo $meta_info['bg-url']; ?>;
}
[...]
```

Comment: the id is stored in the post object for wp, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID

Comment: Yes, but this file isn't connected to WordPress. I can only access WP settings using get_option().

Comment: wordpress wasn't really designed to work outside its infrastructure very well. But I suppose you could manually connect to the WP DB via php and then write a SQl statment to get the post id of the post you are on. without any more information it would be hard to give you an exact answer

Comment: The file is in the theme directory and I try to use it as a dynamic stylesheet where to save info from the custom fields stored in custom meta boxes.

Comment: honestly it sounds like you are going about the process completely wrong to begin with. I would look over at wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'll take a look over there as well, thanks for the suggestion. Why would you say it's wrong, though?

Answer (score 2):

you need to include the files **wp--blog-header.php**, if you include this file you can access all the functions available on wordpress, this is an example:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); 
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```